# Почему не печатается unsigned int?

Tags: c, типы-данных

Есть printf, есть спецификатор unsigned int - %u; Википедия говорит что диапазон unsigned int от 0 до 4294967295.
Но почему когда я делаю так:

```
{
    printf("%u", 4294967295);
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор gcc мне сообщает что я вывожу long int: *" error: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’"*?

Comment: printf("%ul", 4294967295); <-- 4294967295

Comment: printf("%u", sizeof(unsigned int));

Comment: `4294967295u` тип литерала следует указать, иначе он превратится в ближайший знаковый тип подходящего размера - long

Comment: @LShadow77 А вы добавьте `-Wall -Werror`

Comment: @user7860670 добавил, стал ругаться) Без этих опций компилируется, и даже выводит на первый взгляд верный результат. Однако я заподозрил неладное, дизассемблировал результат и увидел *страшное*: константа `4294967295` передаётся в стек, как `long long int`! И если, например, написать `printf("%u %d", 4294967295, 20);`, то закономерно будет выведено ``4294967295 0`, т.к. вместо параметра `20` будет прочитана старшая часть 64-битного `4294967295`. Вот так и выглядят на практике *скрытые ошибки*. В общим, два единственно верных варианта вывода: либо с `4294967295u`, либо с `%llu`.

Comment: @user7860670 дополню про спецификатор `%llu`. С опциями `-Wall -Werror` мой компилятор gcc на него ругается, мол, нет такого спецификатора. Но без этих опций компилируется закономерно корректный код. Так что эти опции могут вставлять лишние палки в колёса. Лучше обходиться без них и писать код более вдумчиво. А спецификатора `%ul`, который привели выше в комментах, не существует. Для вывода `unsigned long long int` и `long long int`, соответственно - `%llu` и `%lld`.

Comment: @LShadow77 *Так что эти опции могут вставлять лишние палки в колёса. Лучше обходиться без них и писать код более вдумчиво.* - нет, надо разбираться с ошибками, если компилятор ругался, что такого спецификатора нет, то значит его действительно не было

Comment: @user7860670 нет, компилятор ругался , что такого спецификатора нет, просто потому, что данная версия компилятора ***не знает*** про существования этого спецификатора! Другими словами, с опциями `-Wall -Werror` компилятор пытается лезть за пределы своих полномочий (проверка синтаксиса C++) и начинает проверять синтаксис строки форматирования в `printf()`, хотя это уже является епархией рантайма. Разработчики GCC тут просто не совсем допилили функционал проверки первого параметра `printf()`. Кстати, вот подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590735/printf-long-long-int-in-c-with-gcc